# OpenCV Android native samples: "non-system libraries in linker flags"

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk, native

first of all sorry for my bad English.

I'm new to OpenCV and have tried to run android samples, but I have problem with samples with native code. When I try to run face-detection I get an error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTF0I.png

Console output looks like:

> 17:37:20 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - face-detection ****
>
> "C:\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build.cmd"
>
> Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:detection_based_tracker: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java
>   Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
>   Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
>   Android NDK:     current module
>   Install        : libdetection_based_tra
>   cker.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so
>
> 17:37:23 Build Finished (took 2s.573ms)

I use eclipse and windows 7.
Any ideas how can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out docs/ANDROID-MK.html in your NDK installation

Comment: do you have `OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on` in your `Android.mk` before `include .../OpenCV.mk` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [non-system libraries in linker flags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669518/non-system-libraries-in-linker-flags)